# Redux Store (returns only initial state) not updating (Actions work perfectly fine)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

When authentication is done I can see the actions updating and the reducer updating -  but then `mapstatetoprops` does not do anything with the new reducer state

**The Store keeps logging the same state(initial state) on every update**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn, signOut } from '../reducer/actions'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

class LoginPage extends React.PureComponent {

  // Configure FirebaseUI.
  uiConfig = {'FirebaseUI Config'}

  componentDidMount = () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => { // gets user object on authentication
      console.log('OnAuthStateChanged', user)
      console.log('Check If Props Change in AuthChange', this.props.isauthed)

      if (user) {
        this.props.signIn(user)
      } else {
        this.props.signOut(user)
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Check If Props Change in Render', this.props.isauthed)
    if (!this.props.isauthed) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>My App</h1>
          <p>Please sign-in:</p>
          <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Redirect to='/' />
    )
  }
}

export default (LoginPage);
```

JS that should dispatch and update the props

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn, signOut } from '../reducer/actions'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('LOGINmapstatetoprops', state.Authed)
  return {
    isauthed: state.Authed.isauthed,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  console.log('LOGINmapDISPATCHoprops')
  return bindActionCreators({signIn, signOut}, dispatch)
}


  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

The reducer

```js
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const initialState = {
  isauthed: false,
  error: ''
}

const AuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log('this is an action', action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'IsSignedIn':
      return {
        ...state,
        isauthed: action.payload
      }
      break;
    case 'IsNotSignedIn':
      return {
        ...state,
        isauthed: action.payload
      }
      break;
    default: return state
  }
}

export default AuthReducer;
```

This is the actions file

```js
export const signIn = (user) => {
  console.log('this is from actions', user)
  return {
    type: 'isSignedIn',
    payload: true
  }
}

export const signOut = (user) => {
  console.log(user)
  return {
    type: 'isNotSignedIn',
    payload: false
  }
}
```

Redux Store

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
import {AllReducers} from './reducer/index';
//import rootEpic from './modules/rootEpic';

//const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic);

const store = createStore(AllReducers);

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('storeupdated', store.getState())
});

export default store;
```

CombineReducers Function

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {AuthReducer} from './AuthReducer'
import {UserReducer} from './UserReducer'

export const AllReducers = combineReducers({
  Authed: AuthReducer 
  User:   UserReducer
})
```

Comment: your actions dispatch action with type `isSignedIn` and `isNotSignedIn` and your reducer expects `IsSignedIn` and `IsNotSignedIn` with capital letters. I'd recommend using all capital letters in action types as they are constants. also as written in the docs https://redux.js.org/basics/actions

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, This was exactly the problem, Silly I forgot this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a typo error between `'isSignedIn'` and `'IsSignedIn'` (first letter differ)

You could avoid that by using a variable declared in a separated file. I like to call it `types.js` for the types of actions:

```
// types.js
export const IS_SIGNED_IN = 'isSignedInOrEvenWhateverButYouBetterKeepAClearName'
// (same with all your types)
```

And then you can import this variable in your other files. You won't have typos anymore!

P.S: you can find all these ideas in redux [documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Silly me how could I miss it, Now It is not redirecting (probably because I'm abusing the connect method